# Progress Dialog not displaying using Context in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, progressdialog

I have a `dialog fragment` Java class which showing a dialog box it works so fine but the only problem is that the progressDialog is not showing while waiting for the response, this is different from the dialog box, this progressDialog works in `AsyncTask` while getting the response from the http.

here is my code:

```
package com.example.kapoyei.hatidtubigan.helper;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.kapoyei.hatidtubigan.R;
import com.example.kapoyei.hatidtubigan.other.Http;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import static android.content.Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;

public class AddStation extends AppCompatDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static String jsonObject; // THIS WILL BE THE HANDLER OF JSON LATER
    Button btnCreate; // GET THE BUTTON
    EditText etStationName, etAddress, etContact; // GET THE INPUT TEXT

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // CREATE A DIALOG BOX

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // GET THE LAYOUT

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_addstation, null);

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        // GET THE VALUES

        etStationName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etStationName);
        etAddress = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
        etContact = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etContact);

        btnCreate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);

        // SET CLICK LISTENER OF THE BUTTON

        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(this);

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.btnCreate) {
            if(etStationName.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etAddress.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etContact.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "All inputs are required!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    Thread stationThread = new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Looper.prepare();
                            String param = "n=" + etStationName.getText().toString() + "&a=" + etAddress.getText().toString() + "&c=" + etContact.getText().toString();
                            String endpoint = Http.url + "?type=addstation&" + param;
                            endpoint = endpoint.replace(" ", "%20");

                            new AddStation.StoreStation(getActivity()).execute(endpoint);
                        }
                    };

                    stationThread.start();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class StoreStation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog pd;

        private Context mContext;

        public StoreStation(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            pd.setMessage("Adding station ...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pd.cancel();
            getResponse(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String data = "";
            jsonObject = "";

            try {
                String link = (String) url[0];
                URL getURL = new URL(link);
                HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) getURL.openConnection();

                huc.setReadTimeout(10000);
                huc.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
                huc.setDoInput(true);
                huc.connect();

                InputStream is = huc.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

                while((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    jsonObject += data;
                }

                Log.i("", jsonObject);

                return jsonObject;

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void getResponse(String json) {
            if(json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("station");

                    String result = "";

                    for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        result = obj.getString("result");
                    }

                    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Successfully save!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("exists")) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Station is already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connection problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return ni != null && ni.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **In Android, only Main thread /UI thread can update UI**

Other thread cannot update UI but your code is trying to run asynch task(which is a thread which run off/on UI accordingly, awesome!) in a worker thread which is causing the issues.

Solution: Execute Asynch task on UI thread

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.btnCreate) {
        if(etStationName.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etAddress.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etContact.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "All inputs are required!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        String param = "n=" + etStationName.getText().toString() + "&a=" + etAddress.getText().toString() + "&c=" + etContact.getText().toString();
                        String endpoint = Http.url + "?type=addstation&" + param;
                        endpoint = endpoint.replace(" ", "%20");

                        new AddStation.StoreStation(getActivity()).execute(endpoint);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```